# Can my nginx module make a connection in the master process?

Tags: plugins, nginx

I'm writing an nginx module that wants to subscribe to a zeromq pubsub socket and update an in-memory data-structure based on the messages it receives. To save bandwidth, it makes sense that only *one* process should make the subscription, and the data structure should be in shm so that all processes can make use of it. To me it seems natural that that one process should be the master (since if it was a worker, the code would have to somehow decide *which* worker).

But when I call `ngx_get_connection` from my `init_master` or `init_module` callbacks, it segfaults, apparently due to `ngx_cycle` not being initialized yet. Google searches on plugins doing work in the master process seem pretty pessimistic. Is there a better way to accomplish my goal of making a single outgoing connection to the pubsub socket per server, regardless of how many workers it has?

Here's a sample of code that works in a worker context but not from the master:

```
void *zmq_context = zmq_ctx_new();
void *control_socket = zmq_socket(zmq_context, ZMQ_SUB);
int control_fd;
size_t fdsize = sizeof(int);
ngx_connection_t *control_connection;

zmq_connect(control_socket, "tcp://somewhere:1234");
zmq_setsockopt(control_socket, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "", 0);
zmq_getsockopt(control_socket, ZMQ_FD, &control_fd, &fdsize);
control_connection = ngx_get_connection(control_fd, cycle->log);
control_connection->read->handler = my_read_handler;
control_connection->read->log = cycle->log;
ngx_add_event(control_connection->read, NGX_READ_EVENT, 0);
```

and elsewhere

```
void my_read_handler (ngx_event_t *ev) {
    int events;
    size_t events_size = sizeof(events);

    zmq_getsockopt(control_socket, ZMQ_EVENTS, &events, &events_size);
    while (events & ZMQ_POLLIN) {
        /* ...
           read a message, do something with it
        ... */
        events = 0;
        zmq_getsockopt(control_socket, ZMQ_EVENTS, &events, &events_size);
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you actually want to introduce potential security hole in nginx. The master process usually works under privileged user and isn't supposed to communicate with external services.

Comment: @VBart I'm open to any option that lets *one* process own the socket.

Comment: (besides which, I'm not using low ports, and can easily run nginx entirely as a regular user).

Answer (score 1):

> To save bandwidth, it makes sense that only one process should make the subscription, and the data structure should be in shm so that all processes can make use of it. To me it seems natural that that one process should be the master (since if it was a worker, the code would have to somehow decide which worker).

As I already said, all you need is to decline your *natural* idea and just use one worker process for your purpose.

Which worker? Well, let it be the first one started.

Comment: You "already said", eh? I certainly haven't seen it before now. Anyway, is there a reasonable guarantee that there will always be a worker running with index 0?

Comment: You may use your shm to control which worker process will do the job, and thus to be sure that there's always one.

Comment: Using `ngx_process_slot == 0` seems to work decently, but would you like to be less cryptic about how someone would use the shm to choose?

Comment: When worker starts it may get a lock, then check and set special flag in shm to indicate for other worker processes that there is already one process assigned for the job.